# how I can get the minimum number of ArrayList<Integer> needed to have all numbers from 1 to "n"?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm looking a simple solution to get the minimum number "ArrayList of Integers" needed to have all numbers from 1 to n, with the next condition:

Each ArrayList must be created from 3 parameters (a, b and n)

"a" and "b" set the numbers in the ArrayList

"n" is the limit

The condition is:

If a ≤ b ===>  a ≤ j ≤ b

if a>b ===> 1 ≤ j ≤ b and a ≤ j ≤ n

Note: "j" are the numbers on the ArrayList.

this is my code:

```
public Integers(int a, int b, int n) {//constructor
    this.numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    makeList(a, b, n);
}

public void makeList(int a, int b, int n) {
    if (a < b) {
        while (a <= b) {
            this.numbers.add(a);
            a++;
        }
    } else {

        int aux = 1;
        while (aux <= b) {
            this.numbers.add(aux);
            aux++;
        }

        int aux2 = a;
        while (aux2 <= n) {
            this.numbers.add(aux2);
            aux2++;
        }

    }
}

public void showNumbers() {
    for (int x = 0; x < this.numbers.size(); x++) {
        System.out.print(this.numbers.get(x) + "\t");
    }

}
```

this is an example with n=20:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integers first= new Integers(1, 10, 20);
    first.showNumbers();//1 2 3 ...8 9 10
    System.out.println();

    Integers second= new Integers(15, 5, 20);
    second.showNumbers();//1 2 3 4 5 15 16 17 18 19 20 
    System.out.println();

    Integers third= new Integers(15, 20, 20);
    third.showNumbers();//15 16 17 18 19 20
    System.out.println();

    Integers fourth= new Integers(4, 17, 20);
    fourth.showNumbers();//4 5 6 ... 15 16 17
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Solution expected is: 2 ====> <second and fourth>");
}
```

and the answer that I expect is 2 (second and fourth).

Comment: What is you expected output for 2nd case ?

Comment: Every use case is fine as per your condition.
Not sure what you required ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what `n` is from the start, it might be simpler to store a boolean array of `n` values. Then every time you construct an `ArrayList`, you just mark off if that value would appear in the `ArrayList`.

Other than this, you pretty much would have to brute-force (I think this would be equivalent to the vertex-cover problem so you'd at best be able to approximate in faster times than brute-forcing).

Hence, I'd try this implementation of your `Integer` class:

```
public class Integer {
    private int a, b;
    private boolean flipped;

    public Integer(int _a, int _b){
        a = Math.min(_a, _b);
        b = Math.max(_a, _b);
        flipped = b < a;
    }

    public void markOff(boolean [] arr){
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(a <= i && i <= b){
                arr[i] = arr[i] || !flipped;
            }else{
                arr[i] = arr[i] || flipped;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in the above, `markOff` just checks if each index would appear in the `ArrayList` you'd create (I'll leave figuring out the boolean logic up to you, but the idea is just to set all the extra elements to true as necessary - so if a new index is covered by the array, you'd mark it off, but you don't un-mark already marked ones.) You can optimize it to not traverse the whole array and look more like your `makeList` if you want to.

In order to find the minimal set of arrays that would cover up to `n`, you'd have to do something like the following:

```
public static int driveSoln(int n, Integer[] covers){
    return helper(covers, new boolean[n], 0, 0);
}

private static int helper(Integer[] covers, boolean[] marked, int idx, int used){
    boolean done;
    for(boolean d: marked) done = done && d;
    if(done) return used;

    if(idx >= covers.length) return -1;

    boolean [] markCopy = marked.clone();
    covers[i].markOff(marked);
    int dontUse = helper(covers, markCopy, idx + 1, used);
    int use = helper(covers, marked, idx + 1, used + 1);
    return Math.min(use, dontUse);
}
```

Intuitively, what I do here is for each inputted cover, chose whether or not to use it and keep looking at the rest. The recursion here "remembers" my choices. I'm guaranteed to (sadly) check all the choices, so this is quite slow, but definitely right. An optimization might be to ignore subsets: if an array only covers items already covered by 1 array, discard it.